# Trying to make a random sprite clickable

Tags: phaser-framework

I would like to ask the gurus of stackoverflow as I know that most of the time I find my answers here, and I want to thank the community for all the vast information on this site, Im a bit stuck on a small little learning projeck I got going and any assistance would be greatly appreciated, this is my code below (I will explain the issue below the code):

```
this.load.atlas('enemies', 'enemies.png','enemies.json');  ####This goes on preload function


    #####everything below I added to create function
    var monsterData = [
            {name: 'Aerocephal', image: 'aerocephal'},
            {name: 'Arcana Drake', image: 'arcana_drake'},
            {name: 'Aurum Drakueli', image: 'aurum-drakueli'},
            {name: 'Bat', image: 'bat'},
            {name: 'Daemarbora', image: 'daemarbora'},
            {name: 'Deceleon', image: 'deceleon'},
            {name: 'Demonic Essence', image: 'demonic_essence'},
            {name: 'Dune Crawler', image: 'dune_crawler'},
            {name: 'Green Slime', image: 'green_slime'},
            {name: 'Nagaruda', image: 'nagaruda'},
            {name: 'Rat', image: 'rat'},
            {name: 'Scorpion', image: 'scorpion'},
            {name: 'Skeleton', image: 'skeleton'},
            {name: 'Snake', image: 'snake'},
            {name: 'Spider', image: 'spider'},
            {name: 'Stygian Lizard', image: 'stygian_lizard'}
        ];

        var monsters = this.add.group();
            var monster;
            let currentmonster = Phaser.Utils.Array.GetRandom(monsterData);
            
            monsterData.forEach(function(data) {
            monster = monsters.create(400,300, 'enemies', currentmonster.image).setOrigin(0.5);
            monster.details = data;  
            
            
            });
            monster.on('pointerdown', function (pointer) {
                this.setTint(0xff0000);
               
            });
            monster.on('pointerout', function (pointer) {
                this.clearTint();
            });
            monster.on('pointerup', function (pointer) {
                this.clearTint();
            });
```

*Basically my monsters do spawn as expected and they do change sprite every time I refresh the page, but the click function does not works, it simply wont click on it, and nothing happens, no errors on console nothing, am I approaching this incorrectly? please any suggestion is greatly appreciated.*

my main functions look like the ones on this tutorial: [Tutorial](https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game/part1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `setInteractive()` method that lets Phaser know a gameobject should listen for input events.

Modify this line:

```
 monster = monsters.create(400,300, 'enemies', currentmonster.image).setOrigin(0.5);
```

To look like this instead:

```
 monster = monsters.create(400,300, 'enemies', currentmonster.image).setOrigin(0.5).setInteractive();
```

You can read more about [setInteractive in the Phaser 3 Docs for Sprite](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite.html#setInteractive__anchor).